# What are some examples of inverted classical inheritance?

Tags: language-agnostic, language-design, inheritance

Are there any examples of inheritance in languages where classes call their subclasses' methods rather than their super classes' methods?

It should not behave like traditional inheritance like the following.

```
Parent.method = function () {
    // Do things
}
Child.method = function () {
    // Do things
    super.method()
    // Do things
}
```

It should instead behave like this.

```
Parent.method = function () {
    // Do things
    sub.method()
    // Do things
}
Child.method = function () {
    // Do things
}
```

Does this pattern have a name?

Comment: That's just abstraction, this is classically how abstract classes are used in C++/Java/C#.

Comment: Take a look at inheritance in Beta language. It is "reversed" compared to what mainstream languages do.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was marked off topic and downvoted so much, but after @amon clued me in to the `inner` keyword and @Thiago Silva mentioned `Beta`, I found this paper which describes what I was originally looking for. http://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/publications/oopsla04-gff.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is common in the [*Strategy Pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):

```java
abstract class Strategy {
  void stepA();
  void stepB();

  void execute() {
    stepA();
    stepB();
  }
}

class SpecificStategy extends Strategy {
  void stepA() { ... }
  void stepB() { ... }
}

new SpecificStrategy().execute();
```

The concept of [*traits*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_%28computer_programming%29) is also built around this: A trait is similar to an abstract base class in that it can define implementations plus interfaces of required methods, which an implementing class must provide.

Some object systems like [*CLOS*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLOS) (for Common Lisp) or [*Moose*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moose_%28Perl%29) (for Perl) also have the ability that a method can refer to `inner`, which is this method's implementation in a subclass. If no subclass provides another implementation, then it is a no-op. Here, defining a method of the same name is different from overriding the method. Perl example:

```perl
package Report {
  use Moose;

  sub display {
    say "Some title:";
    say "";
    inner();
    say " - $_" for qw< foo bar baz >;
  }
}

package SpecificReport {
  use Moose;
  extends 'Report';

  # "augment" avoids overriding the parent implementation
  augment display => sub {
    say "some paragraph";
    say "";
    inner();
  };
}

SpecificReport->display;
```

Output:

```
Some title:

some paragraph

 - foo
 - bar
 - baz
```

Comment: Ah yes, the `inner` reference is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy pattern is more than just a parent class calling subclass methods. It is a generalized solution to inject behavior into objects. The point of Strategy and SpecificStategy is that objects of this type are injected into a context, which then calls Strategy's execute(). In amon's anwer, the implementations of the Strategy classes only incidentally implement the pattern that is the subject of the original question. It is called the [Template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

I don't know why the question has been downvoted, the OP has good reasons to doubt that the classical 'call super' principle is the natural one, and many coding style guides nowadays forbid the use of it by requiring that methods have to be either final or abstract.